Using nbconvert to export a jupyterlab notebook to html with toc?
I'm currently using

jupyterlab 4.1.3
nbconvert 7.16.2

and would like to export a notebook to html with toc.
In earlier versions of nbconvert (v5.x.x) I know we could do
jupyter nbconvert --to html_toc FILENAME.ipynb
However, things seem to have changed in nbconvert v7, and --template is used as an argument in the command:
jupyter nbconvert --to html FILENAME.ipynb --template lab
I wonder what's the idiomatic way to achieve the same thing in the newest version of Jupyterlab and nbconvert, and whether there are existing template with nice toc (e.g. with numbering of the sections). I haven't been able to find a template that replaces the html_toc in the older versions.
Thanks!
